# php/sql need help with query to get last title

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where you enter something and it then shows you the id and title of last row, but as its being created there and then it just shows the previous last row at time of submission,
 ie if last row id is 23 it would show row 23 when I actually want it to show row 24, to get around this I added +1 to id in the query below:

ie:

```
$last_id = $lr_result['id'] + 1;
```

now this works fine for the id but now I'm trying to get the title of the same row but whatever I try I always get the last title (at time of submission),
 ie row 23 title rather then row 24 title (or nothing at all in the case for the snippet below).

```
// fetch id
$lastrow    = "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$lr_result  = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($lastrow));
//fetch id and add 1
$last_id    = $lr_result['id'] + 1;

// fetch title where id = last_id
$lasttitlerow = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id='{$last_id}'";
$ltr_result   = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($lasttitlerow));
$last_title   = $ltr_result['title'];

echo $last_id . $last_title;
```

As always all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but you would need to insert the new row that the user is submitting before it would be in your database. Your code doesn't work because it looks like you are trying to retrieve information about a row that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Holy punctuation, Batman. I can't understand even your first sentence.

Comment: I agree with Brian, if you're selecting the id of the last row, why would the **last row' id + 1** be a valid row?

Comment: @Brian Glaz: ok how to explain this? ..The new row is inserted when user submits form but at the same time I also use the query above so query wants to show row 23, but by adding +1 it shows the correct row 24

Comment: You just need to place your insert code BEFORE the code you posted above. If you do that, you won't need to add 1, and it should work.

Comment: @Brian Glaz: Correct I just did that before reading your answer and its working great, sometimes the thing staring you in the face are the answers lol

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM foo)
```

perhaps? The inner query would return '23', and the outerquery will fetch the entire record. You wouldn't be able to retrieve id=24, because that record doesn't exist yet - you haven't inserted it.

Comment: Your kind of right when you say id 24 doesn't exist but id 24 is created/inserted at time of form submission but as I run the above query at the same time as submission (inserting row 24 into db)  adding +1 returns id 24

Comment: Then do your insert, then use `$new_id =  mysql_insert_id()`, which returns the ID of the last row inserted by the current connection.